# Django Templates - How to display parent object when child is null within a forloop on the child

Tags: django, django-templates

I am looking to list `child model objects` that have a `foreign key` to the `parent` and are related to `request.user`.

This is working fine.

The problem I have is when, I want to list the `parent` model object when there is **no** child attached to `request.user`.

And I want to do this in my django template.

In my case, I am using a boolean field (`completed` in the model to identify whether the child exists.

I am stuck on how to pull out the parent object alone.

I suppose there is two questions:

1. How do I express in my nestedfor loop that if the child object is
   null then only show parent object.
2. When child object is null and only show parent object - how do I get the parent object to be rendered only once?

I thought maybe something like `{%if modela.modela_related_name == None%}` (if there is no child object) then do something else would work. Unfortunately, it looks like I already need to be in the `forloop` to find out whether `modela.modela_related_name == None`

| A header | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent_1 | Parent_Child_1 | Parent_Child_1 |
| Parent_2 | Parent_2Child_1 | Parent_2Child_1 |
| Parent_3 | Parent_3Child_1 | Parent_3Child_1 |
| Parent_4 | (empty) | Parent_4 |

**views**

```
def list_quests(request):
    q = ModelA.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html',{'q':q})
```

**template**

```
{%for modela in q %}
{%for modela in modela.modela_related_name.all %}
 {%if modela .user == request.user and modela %}
    {%if modela .completed == True %}
      complted </br>
    {%elif modela.completed == False%}
    not completed</br>
    {%endif%}
  {%else  %} #<-- this is where I am having a problem.

#if modela doesnt exist then pull out parent object and only show it once.
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

**models**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="title",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) 
    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    quest_name = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="modela_related_name")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `modela.modela_related_name.all` in a variable with [{% with %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) and then checking its length to show the parent if it is 0, and do the rest if not.

```python
{% for modela in q %}
  {% with modela_related_name=modela.modela_related_name.all %}
    {% if modela_related_name.count == 0 %}
      {{ modela.title }} (empty)<br>
    {% else %}
      {% for modelb in modela_related_name %}
        {% if modelb.user == request.user %}
          {% if modelb.completed %}
            Completed<br>
          {% else %}
            Not completed<br>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```